# Angular ui-view not loading properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an application based on Angular 1 and  ui-router. Below is my code of index page

```
<div ng-if="!authenticated">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="authenticated">
        <!-- header start -->
        <div header></div>
        <!-- header end -->
        <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
            <!-- sidebar start -->
            <div sidebar></div>
            <!-- sidebar end -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div ui-view></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- footer start -->
        <div footer></div>
        <!-- footer end -->
    </div>
```

Router Congif :

```
$stateProvider
    .state(CONSTANTS.STATE.LOGIN, {

        url: CONSTANTS.PAGE_URL.LOGIN,
        templateUrl: "./resources/login/login.tpl.html",
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        data: { pageTitle: 'Title for Login'},
        permit : {
            loginRequired: false,
            resources : [ PERMISSIONS.RESOURCES.ALL ]
        }
    }).state('abc', {
            abstract: true,
            url: CONSTANTS.PAGE_URL.BASE,
            controller: 'AbcCtrl',
            templateUrl: "./resources/abc/base/abc.tpl.html"
    }).state('abc.dashboard', {

        url: CONSTANTS.PAGE_URL.DASHBOARD,
        templateUrl: "./resources/abc/dashboard/dashboard.tpl.html",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Title for Dashboard' },
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
        permit : {
            loginRequired : true,
            resources : [ PERMISSIONS.RESOURCES.ALL ]
        }
    }).......
```

**Problem**:
After a user login, the new ui-view shows the view of unauthenticated page for a brief period of time and then loads the authenticated content. How can i avoid this problem?

Comment: show us your router config?

Comment: Use ng-cloak with the ui-view

Comment: I will share the routes later.  Thanks

Comment: @Sajeetharan : router config updated

Answer (score 0):

try to change this

```
<div ng-if="!authenticated">
        <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

To this

```
<div ng-if="!authenticated" ng-cloak>
        <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

ngCloak will prevent this to happen.

Comment: I will check and let you know.  Thanks

Comment: No, it is still the same.